# how to solve piecewise linear programming equation in Python?

Tags: python, optimization

My objective function is:
f(x) =  a*500*pricecat_x + b*500*pricecat_y

where pricecat_x is
1300, where 0 < x_quantity <= 250
1400, where 251 <= x_quantity > 500

and pricecat_y is
1420, where 0 < y_quantity < 400
1390, where 401 < y_quantity <= 500

allowable range of x_quantity is (250, 400)
allowable range of y_quantity is (100, 250)

I've written my code as below.

My aim is to optimise `a` and `b`, which is the amount of `x`, and `y`.

I hit a road block when running the line below:

```
 problem += - a*Q_demand*pricecat_x - b*Q_demand* pricecat_y

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-120-207ebdebfbb6>", line 1, in <module>
    problem += - a*Q_demand*pricecat_x - b*Q_demand* pricecat_y

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tfflow\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 790, in __mul__
    if other != 0:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

wondering if anyone could teach how to perform piecewise linear programming in Python?

Many thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from pulp import *
problem = LpProblem("Volume Aportionment", LpMaximize)

## Constants
# Supplier 1

VA_xmin = 0.5   #min VA - Supplier 1
VA_xmax = 0.8   #max VA - Supplier 1

# Supplier 2
VA_ymin = 0.2   #min VA - Supplier 2
VA_ymax = 0.5   #max VA - Supplier 2

Q_demand = 500

# Pricing Tiers
P1 = np.linspace(0, 500, 51)
pricecat_x = np.piecewise(P1, [P1 <= 250, P1 >= 251], [1324.17, 1309.17])

P2 = np.linspace(0, 500, 51)
pricecat_y = np.piecewise(P2, [P2 <= 400, P2 >= 401], [1419.09, 1394.09])

#pricecat_x = 1305
#pricecat_y = 1342

# define Variables
a = LpVariable(name = "VA1", lowBound=VA_xmin, upBound=VA_xmax, cat="Continuous")
b = LpVariable(name = "VA2", lowBound=VA_ymin, upBound=VA_ymax, cat="Continuous")

# constraints
problem += (a+b)*Q_demand >=500

# objective function
#problem += - weight_x*pricecat_x - weight_y* pricecat_y
problem += - a*Q_demand*pricecat_x - b*Q_demand* pricecat_y


print(problem)

# solving
problem.solve()

for v in problem.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: This is quite a good example similar to yours: https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-programming-and-discrete-optimization-with-python-using-pulp-449f3c5f6e99

Comment: Thanks Simon for the suggestion, sorry i didnt mention clearly, my issue is on how to do piecewise linear optimisation in python...coz i think this is a multiple objective function problem.

Comment: this may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6Uxr2d8Z9Q